# SQL Server rename duplicate entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, common-table-expression

I have a table (TableA) with primary key (**dummy_id**) containing a lot of duplicate invoice numbers (**check_no**)
Duplicates can **MAXIMUM** be up to **6**
I want to keep **one** unchanged and rename the rest having **A,B,C,D,E** in the left part

Example

```
dummy_id    check_no
11537       1/41034             
11539       1/41034             
11542       1/41034             
11545       1/41034             
11516       1/41034             
11486       1/41034
```

should become

```
dummy_id    check_no
11537       1/41034             
11539       A/41034             
11542       B/41034             
11545       C/41034             
11516       D/41034             
11486       E/41034
```

Any ideas more than welcome

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is the order important? In your example letters follow the order of your `dummy_id`?

Comment: What is the order upon which you decide `A`, `B`, `C` etc.? What happens when there is more than 6? Drop from them from the result set?

Comment: You want to keep *one*... which one? A random or is there a criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you can do is assign a *row_number* in a CTE and then update the CTE, using *stuff* to replace the first character with the required sequence.

In the example below, it keeps the row with the lowest *dummy_id* unchanged and updates the rest. Adjust this ordering criteria if necessary.

```
with r as (
  select *, Row_Number() over(partition by check_no order by dummy_id) rn
  from t
)
update r set
  check_no = Stuff(check_no, 1, 1, Char(rn + 63))
where rn > 1;
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f0a213139e4c7b352b4fae4082d9428b)

Comment: this is a wonderfully elegant solution!